# airflow prev_execution_date but with PythonOperator

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm looking to reproduce something similar to this command, but using PythonOperator instead. What I struggle with: call execution_date, prev_execution_date but using a PythonOperator. How should it be inserted in op_kwargs?

```
dag = DAG(
    dag_id="06_templated_query",
    schedule_interval="@daily",
    start_date=dt.datetime(year=2019, month=1, day=1),
    end_date=dt.datetime(year=2019, month=1, day=5),
)

fetch_events = BashOperator(
    task_id="fetch_events",
    bash_command=(
        "mkdir -p /data/events && "
        "curl -o /data/events.json "
        "http://events_api:5000/events?"
        "start_date={{execution_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}}&"
        "end_date={{next_execution_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}}"
    ),
    dag=dag,
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the jinja templates from the python function, but it's better by providing the variables as arguments, to simplify your unit tests.

```py
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from pathlib import Path
import requests

def fetch_events(start_date, end_date):
    events_file_path = Path("/data/events.json")
    events_file_path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    response = requests.get(
        url="http://events_api:5000/events",
        params={
            "start_date": start_date,
            "end_date": end_date,
        }
    )
    with open(events_file_path, "w") as file:
        file.write(response.json())

fetch_events = PythonOperator(
    task_id="fetch_events",
    python_callable=fetch_events,
    dag=dag,
    op_kwargs={
        "start_date": "{{execution_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}}",
        "end_date": "{{next_execution_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}}"
    }
)
```